# Throttling MacBook Pro 16inch(late 2019) even though CPU/GPU temps are not high

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, cpu

Lately it's becoming impossible to use my Mac, it always throttle, I thought it was getting too hot, but I checked the temps and while it was throttling, with Kernel_task at 1000% CPU use, the temps were pretty normal.
I was only running Shadow, which is a gaming streaming service. I tried rendering a video earlier to see if it was a shadow only issue, but same thing happened.

I tried resetting SMC and nvram multiple times, didn't help. Is there any fix without needing to install anything sketchy?

[image: Activity monitor during throttling]

[image: Temp during throttling]

Edit : I tried all the solutions of changing the charging port form left to right, right to left, using in closed clamshell mode, low power mode, even not plugging a power cable at all, nothing works.

Comment: It’s hard to know what your CPU die temperature would be before throttling is in effect. Does your Mac idle properly immediately after restart and with zero apps running?

Comment: @Tetsujin I edited my question to explain, it doesn't, I have read that thread and similar ones before. I have no idea what's causing it but it's sure not which ports are plugged since I tried all combinations.

Comment: @bmike Yesterday a restart seemed to solve the issue, for some time at least, when my Mac was unusable at 1000% kernel_task usage, it's like it's random that's why It's confusing. I would understand if it would happen when I use it for heavy tasks like rendering etc...
But it seems like when it starts throttling, the only thing that will solve the issue is to close everything or restart to let it "cool down" or "rest", otherwise it won't solve by itself.

Comment: It's probably a hardware problem. Take it to an Apple Store or other repair shop.

Comment: @benwiggy aw, I was hoping it wouldn't have to, I'm out of warranty and it's the only computer that I own... They also need like 48 hours for a diagnosis...

Comment: @stackexchanged In my experience, they can usually diagnose on the spot, but the repair may take 2 to 7 days, depending on what it is.

Comment: On a 3-year-old machine, first thought would be dust bunny. You can have a look at that yourself. I dust the machines here twice a year.

Comment: It’s great you can boot to idle. My experience is once the GPU engages on these, it’s hard to get back to cool without 10 minutes of sleep with apps similar to the ones you have. [Only iWork and Safari and a few apps that carefully watch for thermal pressure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410187/5472) tend to let the kernel get back to idle.